# bypass RAISE FORM_TRIGGER_FAILURE in oracle forms

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracleforms

I am trying to create a reset button to clear the form, however i get stopped when my text field is empty.

```
IF (:TREATMENT_BLOCK.TR_NAME IS NULL) THEN
   MESSAGE('Treatment Name field is required.');
   RAISE FORM_TRIGGER_FAILURE;
END IF;
```

I implemented this piece of code in the WHEN_VALIDATE_ITEM but its not working, i cannot bypass the trigger failure to reset the form even if my text fields are null.

Comment: How do you clear the form? What's not working?

Comment: Btw, setting `Required` to `Yes` from `Property Palette` of the item `tr_name` would be enough.

Answer (score 0):

Set form validation to *false*; clear form, and return it back to *true*.

```
declare
  fm_id formmodule;
begin
  fm_id := find_form(:system.current_form);
  set_form_property(fm_id, validation, property_false);
  --
  clear_form;
  -- 
  set_form_property(fm_id, validation, property_true);
end;
```

Because, when you set the property to false,

> ... all internal form validation will be bypassed and **no WHEN-VALIDATE triggers will fire**.